# Optional ZF2 module in application.config.php. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to optionally include some modules in my ZF2 app. The modules are entirely independent with any loaded modules.

In `application.config.php`, in the config array I can just include the main modules, and then, at the end, based on some conditions, to add the optional module. Like this:

```
$config = array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
    ),
    ...
);

if (condition) {
    $config['modules'][] = 'OptionalModule';
}

return $config;
```

Though this works and fixes the problem, I was wondering if there is another way of doing this.

Is it a good approach for this use case? Would there be a nicer way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason to not just include it regardless? Do you depend on its inclusion, or reuse that `condition` in application logic to decide if its made use of later on?

Comment: There's a main app (with the predefined modules) and there's an add-on app. The condition actually checks to see if there are additional files on the file system and if so, it includes the module as well. The point is that the whole set-up should work with and without the addons

Comment: Don't have a good answer for you, but if I am understanding correctly I would suggest not checking disk on every request to make that determination, that can be costly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this by using any of the below two methods:

## Conditionally load module with local application config

application.config.php:

```
<?php
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

$config = [
    // You config
];

$local = __DIR__ . '/application.config.local.php';
if (is_readable($local)) {
    $config = ArrayUtils::merge($config, require($local));
}

return $config;
```

application.config.local.php:

```
<?php

return [
    // Your config
];
```

This enables you to have a base application config and load an additional config *per deployment*. So no `if $condition`, this is determined by your deployment process, which is most times easier to manage.

Note this also works for deployment configs: `application.config.development.php` vs `application.config.production.php`. This is just whatever you like, to suit your needs.

## Conditionally execute code in module config

In your Module.php

```
<?php

namespace MyModule;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

        $config = $sm->get('Config');
        if ($config['mymodule']['enabled'] === true) {
            // condition
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have your module.config.php in your own module folder:

```
<?php

return [
    'mymodule' => [
        'enabled' => true,
    ],
];
```

But if youn  need to disable this in a certain environment, you add this to your `config/autoload/local.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'mymodule' => [
        'enabled' => false,
    ],
];
```